# pygame fullscreen mode exit

Tags: python, pygame

I'm running this little program that loads images to the screen in fullscreen mode but once it loads the program will not exit by any key combination and I end up having to reset the computer to complete whatever else I was doing.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
WIDTH=1366; HEIGHT=768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption('Katso')
PENGUIN = pygame.image.load("assets/download.png")
MICKEY = pygame.image.load("assets/mickey.jpg")
ADV = pygame.image.load("assets/adv.jpg")
CAT = pygame.image.load("assets/cat.jpg")
FLV = pygame.image.load("assets/flavours.jpg")
HALL = pygame.image.load("assets/hallway.jpg")
x = 0; # x coordnate of image
y = 0; # y coordinate of image
screen.blit(PENGUIN,(x,y)); pygame.display.update()
running = True
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.QUIT()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_1:
            screen.blit(MICKEY,(x,y)); pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_2:
            screen.blit(PENGUIN,(x,y)); pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_3:
            screen.blit(ADV,(x,y)); pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_4:
            screen.blit(FLV,(x,y)); pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_5:
            screen.blit(CAT,(x,y)); pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_6:
            screen.blit(HALL,(x,y));pygame.display.update()
pygame.QUIT()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pygame.QUIT` is a constant value (an integer) that is used to check the type of an event. To uninitialize pygame, you have to call `pygame.quit()` (lowercase), but that actually doesn't quit your game but only uninitializes the loaded pygame modules. I think it's only needed to close the window if you've started your game in a tkinter based editor like IDLE.

To quit a game you can just break out of the while loop and let Python end the program as usual, or you can call `sys.exit()`.

Since you can't click on the 'x' button to close the window in fullscreen mode, you have to use a key like <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False  # Set running to False to end the while loop.
```

Comment: You can also [toggle the display mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21980648/6220679).

Comment: Great it worked
For some reason alt f4 worked in no frame mode so I assumed it will work the same way in full screen.

Answer (score 1):

There's a boolean, `running`, that's not being used.

Instead of this:

```
running = True
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.QUIT()
```

...consider doing this:

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Comment: sorry it didnt work, i got stuck on the fullscreen and had to reboot

Comment: Check the documentation for pygame about how to exit: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html

Answer (score 0):

First off I assume that you are using Windows, and that the version is not Windows Vista or earlier. If you are using a macOS, then I can't help you.

If none of those work, and you do end up getting stuck and having to reboot your computer, then this will help you.

These commands work for me when I got stuck in fullscreen:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Just pressing the <kbd>⊞</kbd>(window) key

These both do the same thing, it pushes the window that pygame is opened in all the way to the back, opening the windows sidebar and thus revealing the task bar. It won't actually stop running the program, so if you click on the logo that represents your output, it will just go back to being stuck in fullscreen.