# Pygame Fullscreen Mode Glitch

Tags: python, pygame, windows-10, desktop, visual-glitch

I was just starting a new game with pygame on python 3.6.5 on a Windows 10 PC, when I ended up with a really crazy glitch that I couldn't solve. This is my code, I'll explain my problem afterwards.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

def create_window():
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.FULLSCREEN)


create_window()

isRunning = True

while isRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == K_a:
                isRunning = False


pygame.quit()
```

So when I ran this code, pygame ran as normal, creating a fullscreen black window. Then a mouse appeared and when I pressed on the A key. When I did this, I couldn't exit the pygame window. I went onto Control+Alt+Delete task manager and it showed me the desktop. The graphics had gone a bit less realistic and the screen had zoomed in. The only way to get out was to go onto the task manager and end the python task. Then it went back to the normal desktop. I looked at another project : [pygame fullscreen mode exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592133/pygame-fullscreen-mode-exit) I tried that solution but it didn't work. I kept on trying to find the solution to the strange desktop but couldn't. I'd appreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the black screen because you didn't draw anything.

The code is still running in an infinite loop that's why you have to finish it in task manager.

Pressing **A** does *nothing* because your code doesn't check it correctly:

```
if event.type == K_a:
```

should be

```
if event.key == pygame.K_a:
```

Your desktop is weird because you made pygame change your video card to the 800x600 resolution, which is not your native desktop resolution

Everything is correct and the code is behaving just as you wrote it.

I run the code with the change above and it correctly exited when I pressed `A`

Comment: Literally writing this in the strange fullscreen mode. That's how you know this didn't work. Sorry!

Comment: @Guydangerous99 everything seems to be correct. The behavior you describe is exactly how the code you wrote should behave, so there isn't anything that is **not working**.

Comment: @Guydangerous99 writing code is dangerous! - there was this guy which wrote a code to mess with monitor frequency and the monitor exploded!

Comment: lol, anyway, the guy above solved the problem. At least I know what to do when I troll my friends! ;)

Comment: @Guydangerous99 his answer is exactly the same as mine though, and I answered first - oh well

Comment: oh right wait a sec :) Didn't notice you put `pygame.K_a`

Answer (score 2):

I found multiple problems with your code. Here are some solutions:

The first problem is that you are using `event.type` where you need to be using `event.key`.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.type == pygame.K_a:
            isRunning = False
```

The second `event.type` needs to be changed to an `event.key`.

The second problem is that `K_a` needs to be prefixed with `pygame.`, like this:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_a:
```

Your desktop looked all fuzzy because the PyGame application ran in `800x600` resolution, which is less than most monitors. The PyGame window was still open until you closed it. As long as the window is open, the custom resolution remains.

I hope I've helped you out!

Comment: This worked thanks! :) Now I know what to do if I want to troll my friends :)

Comment: Sorry if this answer looks copied, was typing it when @nosklo answered